# Как повесить обработчик событий на несколько элементов?

Tags: javascript

На странице есть несколько элементов, но событие срабатывает только на первом.
Codepen
При клике открывается только первый список.
Пробовала несколькими способами, некоторые срабатывали, т.е. открывались все списки. Но переставал работать выбор внутри этих списков. Можно проверить разкомментив код в js.
Как повесить событие на все, чтобы при этом выбор элементов работал корректно?

P.S. код для раскрывашки взяла отсюда.
Нашла такой же вопрос, поэтому же коду, но не могу понять как сделать.

```js
    const selectSingle = document.querySelector('.__select');
    const selectSingle_title = selectSingle.querySelector('.__select__title');
    const selectSingle_labels = selectSingle.querySelectorAll('.__select__label');


    // Toggle menu
    selectSingle_title.addEventListener('click', () => {
        if ('active' === selectSingle.getAttribute('data-state')) {
            selectSingle.setAttribute('data-state', '');
        } else {
            selectSingle.setAttribute('data-state', 'active');
        }
    });

    // Close when click to option
    for (let i = 0; i < selectSingle_labels.length; i++) {
        selectSingle_labels[i].addEventListener('click', (evt) => {
            selectSingle_title.textContent = evt.target.textContent;
            selectSingle.setAttribute('data-state', '');
        });
    }

     /*
   const selectSingle = document.querySelectorAll('.__select');
     const selectSingle_title = document.querySelectorAll('.__select__title');
     const selectSingle_labels = document.querySelectorAll('.__select__label');

  [].forEach.call(selectSingle, function(selectSingle_title) {
       selectSingle_title.addEventListener('click', () => {
         if ('active' === selectSingle_title.getAttribute('data-state')) {
           selectSingle_title.setAttribute('data-state', '');
         } else {
          selectSingle_title.setAttribute('data-state', 'active');
        }
      });
    });
for (let i = 0; i < selectSingle_labels.length; i++) {
        selectSingle_labels[i].addEventListener('click', (evt) => {
            selectSingle_title.textContent = evt.target.textContent;
            selectSingle.setAttribute('data-state', '');
        });
    }*/
```

```css
.__select {
    position: relative;
    width: 500px;
    height: 55px;
    border: none;
}

.__select[data-state="active"] .__select__title::before {
    transform: translate(-3px, -50%) rotate(-45deg);
}

.__select[data-state="active"] .__select__title::after {
    transform: translate(3px, -50%) rotate(45deg);
    -webkit-transform: translate(3px, -50%) rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform: translate(3px, -50%) rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform: translate(3px, -50%) rotate(45deg);
    -o-transform: translate(3px, -50%) rotate(45deg);
}

.__select[data-state="active"] .__select__content {
    opacity: 1;
}

.__select[data-state="active"] .__select__label+.__select__input+.__select__label {
    max-height: 40px;
    border-top-width: 1px;
}

.__select[data-state="active"] .__select__title {
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 25px 25px 0 0;
}

.__select[data-state="active"] .form__input-text {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
    -ms-transform: translateY(0);
    transform: translateY(0);
    top: 10px;
    left: 17px;
    font-size: 10px;
    line-height: 12px;
    color: #222222;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.__select__title {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #FFE9B2;
    background: #FFE9B2;
    border-radius: 25px;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 23px 17px 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 25px;
    -moz-border-radius: 25px;
    -ms-border-radius: 25px;
    -o-border-radius: 25px;
}

.__select__title::before,
.__select__title::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: 16px;
    display: block;
    width: 10px;
    height: 2px;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    background-color: #333333;
    transform: translate(-3px, -50%) rotate(45deg);
}

.__select__title::after {
    transform: translate(3px, -50%) rotate(-45deg);
}

.reset {
    display: flex;
    width: 230px;
    padding: 8px 16px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    border: solid 1px #c7ccd1;
    border-radius: 5px;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    color: #333333;

    &:hover {
        background-color: #D8093A;
        color: #ffffff;
    }
}

.__select__content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 54px;
    left: 0;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #ffe9b2;
    border-top: none;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-out;
    transition: all .3s ease-out;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 8;

    label {
        margin: 0;
    }
}

.__select__input {
    display: none;

    &:disabled+label {
        opacity: 0.6;
        pointer-events: none;
    }
}

.__select__label {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    max-height: 0;
    padding: 0 16px;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
    cursor: pointer;
    overflow: hidden;
    font-size: 14px;
}

.__select__label+input+.__select__label {
    border-top: 0 solid #ffe9b2;
}
.form__input-text {
    position: absolute;
    top: 19px;
    left: 17px;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 17px;
    letter-spacing: 0.8px;
    color: #222222;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
```

```html
            <div class="form-input__wrapper">
                <div class="__select" data-state="" for="calendar_type">
                    <div class="__select__title" data-default=""></div>
                    <div class="__select__content" name="calendar_type" id="calendar_type">
                        <input id="singleSelect0" class="__select__input" type="radio" name="singleSelect" />
                        <label for="singleSelect0" class="__select__label"></label>
                        <input id="singleSelect1" class="__select__input" type="radio" name="singleSelect" value="" />
                        <label for="singleSelect1" class="__select__label">И вот такой</label>
                        <input id="singleSelect2" class="__select__input" type="radio" name="singleSelect" value="2"/>
                        <label for="singleSelect2" class="__select__label">Какой-то другой</label>

                    </div>
                    <span class="form__input-text">Тип </span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-input__wrapper">
                <div class="__select" data-state="" for="calendar_type">
                    <div class="__select__title" data-default=""></div>
                    <div class="__select__content" name="calendar_type" id="calendar_type">
                        <input id="singleSelect0" class="__select__input" type="radio" name="singleSelect" />
                        <label for="singleSelect0" class="__select__label"></label>
                        <input id="singleSelect1" class="__select__input" type="radio" name="singleSelect" value="" />
                        <label for="singleSelect1" class="__select__label">Такой</label>
                        <input id="singleSelect2" class="__select__input" type="radio" name="singleSelect" value="2"/>
                        <label for="singleSelect2" class="__select__label">Какой-то другой</label>

                    </div>
                    <span class="form__input-text">Подтип</span>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Приведите, пожалуйста, пример того как вы вешаете событие

Comment: Не смогла вставить ссылки, поэтому добавила код

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const selects = document.querySelectorAll('.__select');
selects.forEach(function(select) {
  select.addEventListener('click', function() {
    let isActive = 'active' === this.getAttribute('data-state');
    selects.forEach(i => i.setAttribute('data-state', ''));
    this.setAttribute('data-state', isActive ? '' : 'active');
  });
  select.querySelectorAll('.__select__label').forEach(function(label) {
    label.addEventListener('click', function() {
      select.setAttribute('data-state', '');
      select.querySelector('.__select__title').textContent = this.textContent;
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.__select {
  position: relative;
  width: 500px;
  height: 55px;
  border: none;
}

.__select[data-state="active"] .__select__title::before {
  transform: translate(-3px, -50%) rotate(-45deg);
}

.__select[data-state="active"] .__select__title::after {
  transform: translate(3px, -50%) rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transform: translate(3px, -50%) rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: translate(3px, -50%) rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: translate(3px, -50%) rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: translate(3px, -50%) rotate(45deg);
}

.__select[data-state="active"] .__select__content {
  opacity: 1;
}

.__select[data-state="active"] .__select__label+.__select__input+.__select__label {
  max-height: 40px;
  border-top-width: 1px;
}

.__select[data-state="active"] .__select__title {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 25px 25px 0 0;
}

.__select[data-state="active"] .form__input-text {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
  -ms-transform: translateY(0);
  transform: translateY(0);
  top: 10px;
  left: 17px;
  font-size: 10px;
  line-height: 12px;
  color: #222222;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.__select__title {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #FFE9B2;
  background: #FFE9B2;
  border-radius: 25px;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 23px 17px 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 25px;
  -moz-border-radius: 25px;
  -ms-border-radius: 25px;
  -o-border-radius: 25px;
}

.__select__title::before,
.__select__title::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 16px;
  display: block;
  width: 10px;
  height: 2px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  background-color: #333333;
  transform: translate(-3px, -50%) rotate(45deg);
}

.__select__title::after {
  transform: translate(3px, -50%) rotate(-45deg);
}

.reset {
  display: flex;
  width: 230px;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border: solid 1px #c7ccd1;
  border-radius: 5px;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  color: #333333;
  &:hover {
    background-color: #D8093A;
    color: #ffffff;
  }
}

.__select__content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 54px;
  left: 0;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ffe9b2;
  border-top: none;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-out;
  transition: all .3s ease-out;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 8;
  label {
    margin: 0;
  }
}

.__select__input {
  display: none;
  &:disabled+label {
    opacity: 0.6;
    pointer-events: none;
  }
}

.__select__label {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  max-height: 0;
  padding: 0 16px;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
  cursor: pointer;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.__select__label+input+.__select__label {
  border-top: 0 solid #ffe9b2;
}

.form__input-text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 19px;
  left: 17px;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 17px;
  letter-spacing: 0.8px;
  color: #222222;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-input__wrapper">
  <div class="__select" data-state="" for="calendar_type">
    <div class="__select__title" data-default=""></div>
    <div class="__select__content" name="calendar_type" id="calendar_type">
      <input id="singleSelect10" class="__select__input" type="radio" name="singleSelect" />
      <label for="singleSelect10" class="__select__label"></label>
      <input id="singleSelect11" class="__select__input" type="radio" name="singleSelect" value="" />
      <label for="singleSelect11" class="__select__label">И вот такой</label>
      <input id="singleSelect12" class="__select__input" type="radio" name="singleSelect" value="2" />
      <label for="singleSelect12" class="__select__label">Какой-то другой</label>
    </div>
    <span class="form__input-text">Тип</span>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-input__wrapper">
  <div class="__select" data-state="" for="calendar_type">
    <div class="__select__title" data-default=""></div>
    <div class="__select__content" name="calendar_type" id="calendar_type">
      <input id="singleSelect20" class="__select__input" type="radio" name="singleSelect" />
      <label for="singleSelect20" class="__select__label"></label>
      <input id="singleSelect21" class="__select__input" type="radio" name="singleSelect" value="" />
      <label for="singleSelect21" class="__select__label">Такой</label>
      <input id="singleSelect22" class="__select__input" type="radio" name="singleSelect" value="2" />
      <label for="singleSelect22" class="__select__label">Какой-то другой</label>
    </div>
    <span class="form__input-text">Подтип</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Как сделать чтобы при нажатии на варианты, они выбирались.Т.е. как у меня в первом селекте?
У вас он просто закрывается.Спасибо.

Comment: Все работает, только при выборе одного, затем  открываются все последующие.
https://codepen.io/lanimya/pen/GRZBxWV
Это можно как-то исправить?

Comment: @SvetlanaTikhonova Вы не скопировали мои изменения в html.

Comment: Спасибо, все заработало, буду дальше разбираться.Тут можно как-то отметить ваш ответ решением вопроса?

Comment: @SvetlanaTikhonova Пожалуйста. Успехов. Можно - значок "галочка" слева от ответа под стрелками.